# Difference between Linux and Windows in Python addressing CSV files

Tags: python, linux, csv, addressing

I'm trying to make the migration from Windows to Linux, some of my Python code has not survived the move.

this is the Windows version:

```
path = r'C:\\Users\\x\\PythonTestFiles\\TestFile.csv'
file = open(path, newline='')
TestFileRaw = csv.reader(file)

header = next(TestFileRaw)
dataPC = [row for row in TestFileRaw]
```

etc....

I'm trying to address a csv file in a certain directory but I can't figure out the Linux addressing.

Can anyone Help?

Comment: why don't you provide file path as a command line argument?

Answer (score 1):

You could use separator from `os` module:

```
import os
path = os.path.join('your_folder_name', 'your_file_name')
```

That way it could be Windows/Linux independent.

Here is [official documentation to os.path module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html).

Comment: On Windows yes. You can use `os.sep` for constructing your path too: on Linux `os.sep = '/'`. I added link to documentation to answer.

Answer (score 1):

here is some info for linux [directory structure](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-directory-structure-and-important-files-paths-explained/)

press **Alt + Enter** over your file then in that properties dialog copy the path to root its something like `/home/<user_name>/Documents` then append that path with `file name` of csv file.

At Final your csv file's path becomes something like

`/home/<user_name>/Documents/filename.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever path is your csv file in linux!

```
path = r'/home/x/python_test_files/test_file.csv'
file = open(path, newline='')
TestFileRaw = csv.reader(file)

header = next(TestFileRaw)
dataPC = [row for row in TestFileRaw]
```